# PECL OAUTH Segmentation Fault

Tags: apache, oauth, pecl

Segmentation Fault generated by combination of Apache/PHP/PECL/Oauth.

Has anyone else experienced/solved a segmentation fault in Apache 2.4.16/php 7.0.13 that is generated by accessing the Wordpress Admin Dashboard/Update/Theme/Plugin (but not other WP Admin pages) and is REMOVED by unininstalling Oauth 2.0.2 (PECL 7.0.13)?

The goal was to enable Oauth authentication in WP which worked but upon an Apache(machine) reboot failed in the way described above, but the problem encompassed WP sites that did and did not use OAUTH (and a variety of versions from 4.4 - 4.7).  So gotta think it's an Apache/PHP/Oauth kind of problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224182/php7-oauth-illegal-memory-allocation

Comment: eh voila...
https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1/issues/81

Comment: If anybody is listening, why does the github solution above applied to Vhost1 seem to have fixed Vhost2.  Is Apache magic?  WTH.